# How to strip leading "./" in unix "find"?

Tags: unix, find, strip

```
find . -type f -print
```

prints out

```
./file1
./file2
./file3
```

Any way to make it print

```
file1
file2
file3
```

?

Comment: if you used `-exec /path/to/myscript.sh {} ` in your `find`,  the `-printf '%P\n'` does not work. Instead, I have to do the `./` prefix chomping inside the script by: `p=${1#"./"}`

Comment: If you are doing it just for a single file: ``f=`find . -name migration`; echo ${f/.\//}``

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If they're only in the current directory

`find * -type f -print`

Is that what you want?

Comment: I knew it could be done with sed, but this is a much better solution. Thanks!

Comment: This will miss files with names that start with a period.

Comment: Bad, depending on a shell settings * may not evaluate to "hidden" files/directories -- those which begins with dot (.) Try to run this command in your home dir, then just "find -type f" and see the difference.

Comment: While, overall, this is a good point, I don't think it applies to this context. If anything, it just makes it more useful. Nothing more annoying then listen your root and getting files like bashrc, htaccess and bash_history.

Comment: A more relevant concern is that '*' is evaluated by the shell. You effectively have a type of malicious code injection situation. It would be trivial to create a file named ' --exec rm ' and another named 'zzzz ;'. Goodbye files.

Comment: Fails on OSX. The answer by Ilia K. is better IMHO.

Comment: This is unsafe. If a file name starts with a dash, it will be treated as an option to find, and may fail, or could potentially do damage.

Comment: Why is `-print` required? It gave same result without that flag.

Comment: This answer should have a disclaimer about the dangers

Comment: tried to use this for folders: `find . -type d -print`, but it still prepends `./` to them

Comment: @ssc the difference is `find *` versus `find .`

Comment: But as the comments above point out, `find *` is simply wrong, and insecure.

Answer (score 306):

Find only regular files under current directory, and print them without "`./`" prefix:

```
find -type f -printf '%P\n'
```

From man find, description of `-printf` format:

> %P     File's name with the name of the command line argument under which it was found removed.

Comment: +1 Good solution if your version of `find` supports `-printf` (not all do).

Comment: As Todd said, but more precisely: it ain't POSIX 7.

Comment: Supported or not, it's definitely safer than the accepted answer.

Comment: You can use `\0` instead of `\n` if you want to pipe it to `xargs -0` (eg in case filenames contain whitespace), eg `find -type f -printf '%P\0' | xargs -0 head`

Comment: @Quanlong , it works on macOS if you `brew install findutils` ;)

Comment: to elaborate on @blockloop's comment: on OS X, install `findutils`, and use `gfind` instead of `find`. That installs GNU find.

Comment: I recommend using `brew install findutils --with-default-names` to prevent adding the `g` prefix if you prefer the GNU tools. If you exclude the flag then yes, you will need to use the `g` prefix.

Comment: If you need to quote the file paths in a shell-safe manner, you could do `find … -printf '%P\0' | xargs -0r printf '%q\n'`. See `man printf` for what `%q` does.

Comment: I like `-printf '%P\n'` , but the path inside a shell script via `-exec myscript.sh {} \;` still contains the `./` thing in the path

Comment: Busybox v1.30.1 (used in the current `docker:latest` image) find also does not seem to support `-printf`

Answer (score 68):

Use sed

```
find . | sed "s|^\./||"
```

Comment: This is my preferred solution; it is POSIX-compatible (works practically everywhere, even embedded systems), very short, and unlikely to result in unexpected behavior. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: How would this be combined with `find -exec`?

Comment: `find -exec sh -c "echo {} | sed 's|^\./||'" \;`

or    

`find -exec sh -c "sed 's|^\./||' <<< '{}'" \;`

Answer (score 8):

it can be shorter

```
find * -type f
```

Comment: Better with `2> /dev/null` to ignore error reported when the command is run in an empty directory.

Comment: Unsafe, just like the accepted answer. `*` is expanded by the shell, so any filename starting with `-` will be interpreted as an option to `find`.

Answer (score 8):

Another way of stripping the `./` is by using `cut` like:

```
find -type f | cut -c3-
```

Further explanation can be found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/331713/343429)

Comment: Good solution if you're processing line-delimited but doesn't work null-delimited.

Answer (score 4):

Since `-printf` option is not available on OSX `find` here is one command that works on OSX find, just in case if someone doesn't want to install `gnu find` using `brew` etc:

```
find . -type f -execdir printf '%s\n' {} +
```

Comment: Unfortunately this strips the whole path of each found file, including intermediate subdirectories, and just prints the filename itself.

Comment: You are right. This solution is only good for files in current directory. For nested files we need to use: `find . -type f -exec bash -c 'for f; do echo "${f#./}"; done' {} +`

Answer (score 2):

For files in current directory:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | xargs basename -a

-maxdepth 1 -> basically this means don't look in subdirectories, just current dir
-type f     -> find only regular files (including hidden ones)
basename    -> strip everything in front of actual file name (remove directory part)
-a          -> 'basename' tool with '-a' option will accept more than one file (batch mode)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of stripping the ./

```
find * -type d -maxdepth 0
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Unsafe, just like the accepted answer. `*` is expanded by the shell, so any filename starting with `-` will be interpreted as an option to `find`.