# Get xargs to word-split placeholder {}

Tags: bash, xargs

(Though [*word splitting*](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/wordsplit) has a specific definition in Bash, in this post it means *to split on spaces or tabs*.)

Demonstrating the question using this input to xargs,

```
$ cat input.txt
LineOneWithOneArg
LineTwo WithTwoArgs
LineThree WithThree Args
LineFour  With  Double  Spaces
```

and this Bash command to echo the arguments passed to it,

```
$ bash -c 'IFS=,; echo "$*"' arg0 arg1 arg2 arg3
arg1,arg2,arg3
```

notice how `xargs -L1` word-splits each line into multiple arguments.

```
$ xargs <input.txt -L1 bash -c 'IFS=,; echo "$*"' arg0
LineOneWithOneArg
LineTwo,WithTwoArgs
LineThree,WithThree,Args
LineFour,With,Double,Spaces
```

However, `xargs -I{}` expands the whole line into `{}` as a single argument.

```
$ xargs <input.txt -I{} bash -c 'IFS=,; echo "$*"' arg0 {}
LineOneWithOneArg
LineTwo WithTwoArgs
LineThree WithThree Args
LineFour  With  Double  Spaces
```

While this is perfectly reasonable behavior for the vast majority of cases, there are times when word-splitting behavior (the first `xargs` example) is preferred.

And while `xargs -L1` can be seen as a workaround, it can only be used to place arguments at the *end* of the command line, making it impossible to express

```
$ xargs -I{} command first-arg {} last-arg
```

with `xargs -L1`. (That is of course, unless `command` is able to accept arguments in a different order, as is the case with options.)

**Is there any way to get `xargs -I{}` to word-split each line when expanding the `{}` placeholder?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sort of.

```
echo -e "1\n2 3" | xargs sh -c 'echo a "$@" b' "$0"
```

Outputs:

```
a 1 2 3 b
```

ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35612138/1563960

Also:

```
echo -e "1\n2 3" | xargs -L1 sh -c 'echo a "$@" b' "$0"
```

Outputs:

```
a 1 b
a 2 3 b
```

Comment: Ah, interesting... This works around the problem by wrapping the desired command to be executed by `xargs` in a shell, so that `xargs` to passes arguments to the shell. Then the shell script references the word-split arguments via the `$@` variable. Clever!

Comment: Thanks! But wait, didn't you want two results in this case?
`a 1 b` and
`a 2 3 b`?

Comment: This is actually a perfect solution, using the shell wrapper together with `$@`. Did you mean something else?

Comment: I wasn't sure whether you wanted the output for my example to be `a 1 2 3 b` on one line or `a 1 b` and `a 2 3 b` on two lines, so I edited my answer to include both options.

Comment: Ah, thanks for clarifying. In my original examples I've used either `-L1` or `-I{}` both of which take consume one line of input per command invocation. It can't hurt to have other alternatives of course. 