# Docker backup and restore for MongoDB failing to restore any data

Tags: mongodb, docker

I have working commands to backup and restore a docker volume for my mongodb docker container, the name of my docker container is `tsl.api.example.db.container`

Ok here we go:
I verify that I have 3 records in a MongoDb collection called `example`.

I add a `test.txt` file `tsl.api.example.db.container`'s volume /data/db to help prove that I am archiving and correctly restoring:

```
docker exec -it tsl.api.example.db.container bash
cd /data/db
touch text.txt
```

My back up command is

docker run --rm --volumes-from tsl.api.example.db.container -v /backup/volumes:/backup tsl.devops.basic.image tar cvf /backup/backup.tar -C /data/db .

Path `/data/db` [is correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7JWJ.png) MongoDb path and is my volume for my container.

I verify backup.tar exists in /backup/volumes on the localhost:
[image]

I now shut down tsl.api.example.db container:

```
docker rm -fv tsl.api.example.db container
```

And then delete it's dangling volume:

```
docker volume prune
```

Screenshot of previous two steps:
[image]

I then start a new container called `tsl.api.example.db.container.2`,that uses the same image that `tsl.api.example.db.container` used , it is running fine, I query mongodb and the `example` collection has no records.

I restore the volume backup.tar to the new container with command

docker run --rm --volumes-from tsl.api.example.db.container.2 -v /backup/volumes:/backup tsl.devops.basic.image bash -c "cd /data/db && tar -xvf /backup/backup.tar"

The backup.tar archive is successfully unpacked and copied to `tsl.api.example.db.container.2`'s volume /data/db, I can see my text.txt to help prove that I archived and unpacked correctly into the new container's volume.

[image]

**And yet, my example collection still has 0 records, I expected the 3 records that existed in my first container, when I archived /data/db**

So I try stopping and starting my new MongoDB container to see if that will refresh my collections:

```
docker stop tsl.api.example.db.container.2
docker start tsl.api.example.db.container.2
```

And of course, the container will not start back up, and here is the last log entries:

[image]

Any suggestions on what files to possibly exclude when trying to restore a MongoDB Docker container volume? Should I exclude aka not archive the mongod.lock when I backup.tar? Any other suggestions?

Comment: I think the core of the problem is in how you packed the backup file. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18681595/tar-a-directory-but-dont-store-full-absolute-paths-in-the-archive.

Comment: yes you are correct @nicooga

Comment: I fixed that problem, thanks for your assistance @nicooga. I also altered my question now, my working tar archive, when unpacked does not restore any data to a new mongodb container and new associated volume