# tar folder and exclude all subfolders, then tar to specific path

Tags: linux, shell, tar

Is there a tar command to exclude sub-directories but include every file in the root of the folder and then place them at specific path?

I would like to omit every subdir, and only keep files max-min depth = 1
I have tried the follwing but its not working:

`tar -cvf r.tar --exclude='~/root-dir/[subdir, ... ]' ~/Desktop`

```
root-dir/
|
├── subdir/
│   ├── subdir/
│   │   └── a.txt
│   |
│   ├── subdir/
│   │   └── b.txt
│   │
│   └── c.txt
├── subdir/
│   ├── subdir/
│   │   └── d.txt
│   │   
│   ├── subdir/
│   │   └── subdir/
│   │       └── subdir/
|   |           └── subdir/...
|   
|
└── apple.txt
└── banana.image
└── ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first, use `find` to find the files meeting your criteria:

```
find ~/Desktop -type f -maxdepth 1
```

then pipe it to tar, [using `-T` ( or `--files-from`) to tell `tar` to get the list of files from `stdin`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/492308/portable-way-to-invoke-tar-with-a-list-of-files-from-stdin):

```
 find ~/Desktop -type f -maxdepth 1 | \
tar -T - cvf r.tar
```

Comment: Wow thank you! this was exactly what i was looking for. Is there another option to prevent the files from being placed into there respective path folders; i.e. `/home/Desktop/files` -> `/files` when extracted?

Comment: For that, you want `-C`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18681595/tar-a-directory-but-dont-store-full-absolute-paths-in-the-archive