# How to include the -C option when creating the tar file in nodejs tar?

Tags: javascript, node.js

We have `-C` option in linux to [remove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18681595/tar-a-directory-but-dont-store-full-absolute-paths-in-the-archive) the absolute path. I am trying to achieve the problem in Node.js

```
tar.create({
        gzip: true,
        file: 'test.tar.gz'
    },
    ['../result/1670341264809/test/']
).then(_ => {
});
```

but with the above code it is creating the tar file with all absolute path, but I need tar file only from test folder.
How to add the flag in node-js module.?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, we have to add path in `cwd`, then provide the directory name on folder array

```
tar.create({
        gzip: true,
        file: 'test.tar.gz',
        cwd: "../result/1670341264809/",
    },
    ['test']
).then(_ => {
    signedPkgName = remoteDir + "testaddon.tar.sign.gz";
    transferFileToRemote();
});
```