# In the Mac terminal, I want to find certain files in current directory, but the output is not what I want?

Tags: macos, unix, terminal, find

find -E .-regex '.*.java$'
The output are as follows, why there are './' in the beginning?
How can I remove the './' in the output?

```
MacBook-Pro:Code fqyuan$ find -E . -regex '.*\.java$'
output is:
./GZIPcompress.java
./SubsetsII.java
./Ugly.java
```

Comment: Do you need a regex? `find . -type f -name '*.java'` should find all the Java files with simple globbing. See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2596462/1531971

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the S.E. related sites http://apple.stackexchange.com  (AskDifferent) OR http://SuperUser.com . Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it there. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `cut` to select only specific part of line:

```
find -E . -regex '.*\.java$' | cut -c3-
```

`cut -c3-` will only select 3rd, 4th, 5th, ... characters only.

BTW, instead of using `-E` and `-regex` option, the `find` command can be simplified using `-name` option:

```
find . -name '*.java' | cut -c3-
```