# complex find -exec with modified basename {} syntax

Tags: bash, sed, find, cut

**Setup**

I have a simple 1 line bash shell script.  Its purpose, is to find all the files in a specific dir. Execute a curl POST of each file.. then move the files to a "old" dir.

**Current attempt**

Below is the find command I'm using.. I'm going to put it on multiple lines for easier reading, but it is all the same line in my script

```
sudo find . -type f 
-exec curl -vX POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" 
-H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -d @{} -u username:password 
"http://192.168.105.10/homeaccess/services/aCStats/uploadData?username=vangeeij&filename=$(basename {})" \; 
-exec sudo mv {} /home/vangeeij/acserver/resultsOld \;
```

**Problem**

Every part of the command works as desired except one part:

```
&filename=$(basename {})
```

I have tried every way I can think of to get the `{}` output from the find command to be placed directly after the equals sign and NOT have the leading  `./` in front of the file name.

Earlier in the command `-d @{}`  I need the `./`  But here I don't

**Previously Tried and failed**

```
filename=$(basename {})
filename=$('echo {} | sed "s|^\./||"')
```

honestly the list goes on and on...

**Question**

In the exact usage above, how can I append the file name, minus the leading `./` directly after the `filename=` in the URL

Comment: see if this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/2596653 helps, or try out others in that thread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest changing your `find` and `curl` to this simple loop in `bash`:

```
while IFS= read -d '' -r file; do
   base=$(basename "$file")
   curl -vX POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" \
      -d @"$file" -u username:password \
      "http://192.168.105.10/homeaccess/services/aCStats/uploadData?username=vangeeij&filename=$base"
   sudo mv "$file" /home/vangeeij/acserver/resultsOld
done < <(sudo find . -type f -print0)
```

We are using **process substitution** here in a `while/done` loop to get these benefits:

1. It will handle files with white spaces / glob characters due to use of `-print0` and `while IFS= read -d '' -r file`
2. It will avoid subshell creation for every file as the case with code in question

Comment: This did the trick... I also preferred to keep the mv command in tact.  Though I was hoping to pull it off with a single find command.. this solution is easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `bash -c` to execute your commands:

```
find . -type f -exec bash -c \
'curl -vX POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -d @{} -u username:password \
"http://192.168.105.10/homeaccess/services/aCStats/uploadData?username=vangeeij&filename=${1##*/} " \
-o /home/vangeeij/acserver/resultsOld/${1##*/}' _ {} \;
```

or as a one liner:

```
find . -type f -exec bash -c 'curl -vX POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -d @{} -u username:password "http://192.168.105.10/homeaccess/services/aCStats/uploadData?username=vangeeij&filename=${1##*/} " -o /home/vangeeij/acserver/resultsOld/${1##*/}' _ {} \;
```

The file names can then be handled as positional parameters and you can use Bash parameter expansion instead of `basename`.

You can avoid the use of `mv` by using the `-o`(output) flag in your `curl`.

More on this technique on [Greg's wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind#Complex_actions).