# Remove special characters from "find" output

Tags: linux, shell, find

I am trying the list all the subfolders within a folder:

```
find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 2>/dev/null | while read dir
do 
  echo $dir

done
```

However, what I get printed out is

```
./dir1
./dir2
```

while I would need only

```
dir1
dir2
```

Complete use case:
later, I would like to create a new file with name of the folder e.g:

```
find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 2>/dev/null | while read dir
do 
  echo 'MOVING TO'$dir
  cd $dir
  #SUMMARYLOG=$dir_log_merged # HERE IS WHERE THE ./ IS PROBLEMATIC
  # QUESTION EDITED
  SUMMARYLOG=${dir}_log_merged # HERE IS WHERE THE ./ IS PROBLEMATIC

  echo -e "\n""\n"'SUMMARY LOGS TO '$SUMMARYLOG
  touch $SUMMARYLOG
  pwd

  find . -size +0c -type f -name '*.err'  | xargs -I % sh -c  'echo % >> {$SUMMARYLOG}; cat % >> "{$SUMMARYLOG}"; echo -e "\n" >> "{$SUMMARYLOG}"'

  cat $SUMMARYLOG
  cd ..
done
```

Basically, I would like to merge a set of `.err` files in each of the subfolders and create one file with the subfolder name.
I can not create my `$SUMMARYLOG` so I think the problem is in the find output `./dir`...

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/2596462/72178.

Comment: You shouldn't fix bugs in the question, as it partially invalidates answer that were given based on the original question.

Comment: apologizes. I will make clear there was an edit

Comment: I've rolled the edit back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `find` acrobatics, you could use a glob and parameter expansion:

```
for d in */; do echo "${d%/}"; done
```

where the `"${d%/}"` removes the trailing slash from each directory name.

If you have hidden directories, you have to add a second glob as `*/` ignores them:

```
for d in */ .[!.]*/; do echo "${d%/}"; done
```

where `.[!.]*/` is a glob for "begins with `.` and is followed by anything but another `.`", to exclude `.` and `..`.

Apart from that, if you have `$dir`, you can't use `$dir_log_merged` to append `_log_merged` to it, as Bash will look for a variable called `dir_log_merged`. You have to use `${dir}_log_merged` instead.

Another set of  problems is in your `xargs` command that starts with

```
sh -c  'echo % >> {$SUMMARYLOG};
```

- Single quotes prevent variables from expanding
- `SUMMARYLOG` would be invisible in the subshell; you'd have to `export` it first
- `{$SUMMARYLOG}` expands to the contents of `$SUMMARYLOG` (empty string, in your case), then surrounds that with `{}`, which is why you see the `{}` file being created
- You can't use `%` like this within the `sh -c` command. You have to use it as an argument to `sh -c` and then refer to it like this:

  ```
  sh -c 'echo "$1"' _ %
  ```

  with `_` as a dummy argument that becomes `$0` within the `sh -c` command.

And finally, I would solve your task as follows:

```
for f in */*.err; do
    ! [[ -s $f ]] && continue           # Skip empty files
    {
        echo "${f##*/}"                 # Basename of file
        cat "$f"                        # File contents
        echo                            # Empty line
    } >> "${f%/*}/${f%/*}_log_merged"   # Dirname plus new filename
done
```

Comment: thanks. We are getting close. I think I have messed up also with the file names given to the xargs command. I am now able to create files with right content, but they are named {} instead of my desired name. what is still wrong?

Comment: @Liborio Are the `.err` files directly in the subdirectories, or nested in sub-subdirectories?

Comment: directly in the subdirectories