# Find command: I don't want to print the leading dot slash (./)

Tags: linux, find

When I issue a `find` command:

```bash
$ find . -type f
./Makefile
./main.py
./pkg
./pkg/__init__.py
```

The output is almost what I want, except for the leading `./`. I understand that I can use other commands such as `sed` to remove the part, but want to know if there is something within `find` which can accomplish the same?

My Expected output is:

```
Makefile
main.py
pkg
pkg/__init__.py
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596462/how-to-strip-leading-in-unix-find - please search before asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to strip leading "./" in unix "find"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596462/how-to-strip-leading-in-unix-find)

Comment: I did search, but not found what I want. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will usually be equivalent:

```
find * -type f
```

The difference is if there are any dot-files in the current directory, they won't be included in the results because `*` doesn't match files that begin with `.`.

This could also get a "command too long" error if the current directory has too many files (in the thousands).